# Why do I get error 424 when calling a function?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I wrote a sub to define the border of a cell in Excel:

```
Sub Borderline(cell As Range)

With C.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
       .LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .ColorIndex = 0
       .TintAndShade = 0
       .Weight = xlThin
End With

End Sub
```

Yet, when I call it, I get error 424:

```
Sub Sub_1()

Dim C As Range

Set C = Range("e1")

Borderline C

End Sub
```

Why?

Comment: `With C.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)` -> `With cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)`. You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.

Comment: Why do I need Option Explicit?

Comment: Because it would flag `C` as an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long story:**

When you are calling the sub with `Borderline C`, the argument `C` is "translated" into the parameter `cell`. The new sub `Sub Borderline(cell As Range)` does not know what the `C` is, but has quite a good idea what `cell` is. Although they are the same. As it has no idea what `C` is, when `C` is called here - `With C.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)`, it throws 424 error.

**Short story:**

At the beginning of your VBA journey, make sure that you call both the parameters and the arguments the same way. Thus, if you call a function with `Borderline C`, make sure that the accepted parameter is `Sub Borderline(C as Range)` and you will have one less problem to take care of.

**The working code:**

```
Sub Borderline(c As Range)

    With c.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

End Sub

Sub Sub1()

    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("E11")
    Borderline c

End Sub
```